# Why Unity interception cannot catch Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, aop, unity-interception

I got an issue with Unity interception when throw an Exception in my method. Please reference from my sample application as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IInterface1, Implementation1>();

        container.RegisterType<ICallHandler, AuditLoggingCallHandler>();

        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUnityContainer), container);
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        container.Configure<Interception>()
            .SetInterceptorFor<IInterface1>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

        var service = container.Resolve<IInterface1>();

        service.Method1("xyz");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The AuditLogging behavior implement following code below:

```
public class AuditLoggingAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container.Resolve<ICallHandler>();
    }
}

public class AuditLoggingCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, 
    GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
        logEntry.Message = "[BEGIN] " + input.MethodBase.Name + "()";
        Logger.Write(logEntry);

        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);

        if (result.Exception != null)
        {
            logEntry = new LogEntry();
            logEntry.Message = " [EXCEPTION] " + input.MethodBase.Name 
             + "." + input.MethodBase.Name 
             + "() ";

            logEntry.ExtendedProperties
            .Add("Exception Message", result.Exception.Message);
            logEntry.ExtendedProperties
            .Add("Exception StackTrace", result.Exception.StackTrace);
            Logger.Write(logEntry);
        }

        logEntry = new LogEntry();
        logEntry.Message = " [FINISH] " + input.MethodBase.Name + "()";

        if (result.ReturnValue != null)
        {
            logEntry
            .ExtendedProperties
            .Add("Return value", result.ReturnValue.ToString());
        }

        Logger.Write(logEntry);

        return result;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And the Interface1.cs and Implementation1.cs are below:

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    [AuditLogging]
    IEnumerable<string> Method1(string name);
}

public class Implementation1 : IInterface1
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Method1(string name)
    {
        if (name.Equals("xyz"))
        {
            throw new Exception("xyz are not allow");
        }

        yield return "ABC";
    }
}
```

The logging file point out the Exception does not write down.There is some thing I am missing or the Unity interception cannot working as expected. 
Here the log file below, it should have `[EXCEPTION]` but there is nothing like that:

```
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 5/30/2013 9:29:07 AM

Message: [BEGIN] Method1()

Category: General

Priority: -1

EventId: 0

Severity: Information

Title:

Machine: XXXY

App Domain: ConsoleApplication10.vshost.exe

ProcessId: 8228

Thread Name: 

Win32 ThreadId:1280

Extended Properties: Parameter values - [(String) name =  'xyz']

----------------------------------------
```

BTW, I using the Enterprise Library version 5 and Unity version 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at here is `yield return "ABC"`. When we apply `yield return` the method will be executed under lazy mode so the `Exception` still not raised. The `exception` only raise after the `MethodReturn` return by interceptor. You change the code as below will see `[EXCEPTION]` will be logged into the file:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Method1(string name)
    {
        if (name.Equals("xyz"))
        {
            throw new Exception("xyz are not allow");
        }

        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("ABC");
        return list;

        //yield return "ABC";
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. I found root cause with your help and understand why the Exception does not logged correctly.